# Google Tag Manager Data Layer macro not passing value to a custom Tag

Tags: google-tag-manager, data-layer

I have setup a `Data Layer Variable` type macro named `orderTotal` which is linked to a variable I am pushing through on the checkout page.

In my custom HTML tag I am doing following:

```
var order_tot = {{orderTotal}};
```

But the issue is that when I test and look at the page source via browser I am getting following instead of actual data:

```
order_tot=google_tag_manager["GTM-[container id]"].macro(2)
```

Same thing is happening with another macro of similar type.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4):

Actually that probably means it's working.  GTM packs all your tags javascript functions that are injected into your page. Having a string literal like "{{macro}}" in there would be no good, so GTM replaces this with a call to a method that retrieves the intended value (case in point, GTM does the same with my macros and they work beautifully).