# Get the proper json output with javascript map function in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, google-tag-manager

I have this json structure datalayer in GTM where I want to get specific json outcome. I´m trying to use the javascript map function with GTM variable for that, but it just return only the whole string with values. Below the initial json structure that I´m fetching:

```
dataLayer.push({
  ecommerce: {
    currencyCode: "USD",
    purchase: {
      actionField: {
        id: "xxx",
        revenue: xxx,
        tax: 0,
        shipping: xxx,
        coupon: "",
        discountAmount: 0,
        affiliation: "xxx"
      },
      products: [
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "product1",
          price: xxx,
          unitPriceLessTax: xxx,
          unitPriceWithTax: xxx,
          taxRate: 0,
          quantity: 2,
          category: "",
          brand: "",
          dimension10: "xxx"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          name: "product2",
          price: xxx,
          unitPriceLessTax: xxx,
          unitPriceWithTax: xxx,
          taxRate: 0,
          quantity: 1,
          category: "",
          brand: "",
          dimension10: "xxx",
          variant: "xxx"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

As a first starting point I´m trying to retrieve first the `product_quantity` and the `product_name` key values using a mapping javascript function:

```
 function() {
      var products = {{DLV - Product Name}}; // this DLV is just the products array
      return products.map(function(prod) { return prod.quantity; });
    }

function() {
          var products = {{DLV - Product Name}}; // this DLV is just the products array
          return products.map(function(prod) { return prod.name; });
        }
```

The problem is that I get as result **2,1** and **product1,product2**.

So when I´m wrapping up like below:

```
var result = {

lineitems : [{
        quantity : "{{Product Quantity}}",
        productName: "{{Product Name}}",

    }]

}
```

I'm getting this outcome below:

```
{
  "lineitems": [
    {
      "quantity": "1,2"
    },
    {
      "productName": "product1, product2"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I fetch each single values to get this expected json structure?

```
 {
      "lineitems": [
        {
          "productName": "product1",
          "quantity": "2,"
        },
        {
          "productName":"product2",
          "quantity": "1,"
        }
      ]
    }
```

#### Update

When I pass the returned object result from the custom variable function to the main GTM tag it shows me in debug mode not the object json result, but something like `google_tag_manager[XXX].macro(187)`.

Not sure why it doesn´t show the data result calculated with the Javascript map function.

Comment: Why do you even want to map them? they contain already what you need. Just ignore the other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you're getting `google_tag_manager[XXX].macro(187)` is because GTM resolves all the variables in the GTM tag upon injection.

i.e. once the element has been added to the end of  and the browser is queued up to execute the code within. Until the variables are resolved, they appear as **function calls to this .macro() method** - it's GTM's internal method that returns the User-Defined Variable values.

First you need to wrap the map function by creating a Custom Variable called `your_variable_name` as following:

```
function() {
  var products = {{DLV - Product Name}};
  return products.map(function(_){ return {
    "quantity":_.quantity,
    "productName":_.name }});
}
```

Now at this point you need to pass this result to the GTM tag as `{{ your_variable_name }}`.

If you check in Preview mode, GTM has not yet injected the tag - it just shows what the tag code looks like pre-injection.

```
//In other words this method with the javascript map function will output the expected json once you'll publish the GTM tag

google_tag_manager[XXX].macro(187) =

{
      "lineitems": [
        {
          "productName": "product1",
          "quantity": "2,"
        },
        {
          "productName":"product2",
          "quantity": "1,"
        }
      ]
    }
```

#### Publish the GTM tag and you'll see the calculated result

- if you custom javascript variable returns the proper json object result, **then it is working as expected**.
- the debug preview mode in GTM won't show you any json result untill you don't publish it.
- you can test it out by submitting and publishing the changes in your GTM workspace.
- check [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816179/google-tag-manager-data-layer-macro-not-passing-value-to-a-custom-tag) which exactly reproduces your case scenario.

Comment: You were right!! After publishing the GTM tag it showed the json result correctly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

By letting your map function callback return multiple keys, like so:

```
var expectedJson = {"lineitems": products.map(_ => { return {"quantity":_.quantity, "productName":_.name}})}
```

edit:
in JS < ECMASCRIPT_2015, without the arrow function:

```
var expectedJson = {"lineitems": products.map(function(_){ return {"quantity":_.quantity, "productName":_.name}})}
```

Comment: Since I´m working with GTM datalayer it says ´This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: arrow function.´

Comment: I have tried to use the second map function and return it. But when I try to run it I get result :"[object Object]"

Comment: @UgoL Somewhere in your code you're translating your results into a string. I have no idea how GTM works, but if I have to guess, I think you need to remove the quotes from your GTM magic call: `lineitems : "{{Product Whatever}}"` to `lineitems : {{Product Whatever}}`.

Comment: If I return the result with JSON.stringify then I see the correct result but all in whole strange string format with many  \\x22 , like this: [{\\x22quantity\\x22:2....etc.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with GTM. There's clearing some escaping going on. `\\x22` means `"`. Perhaps GTM expects only strings as a result? If so:
`var expectedJson = {"lineitems": JSON.stringify(products.map(function(_){ return {"quantity":_.quantity, "productName":_.name}}))}`. But it sounds like you're not sure either, so perhaps dive a bit more into the docs?

Answer (score 0):

According by the code you've passed, you can filter the only columns you want by the following code:

```
var a = { ecommerce: {
    currencyCode: "USD",
    purchase: {
      actionField: {
        id: "xxx",
        revenue: "xxx",
        tax: 0,
        shipping: "xxx",
        coupon: "",
        discountAmount: 0,
        affiliation: "xxx"
      },
      products: [
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "product1",
          price: "xxx",
          unitPriceLessTax: "xxx",
          unitPriceWithTax: "xxx",
          taxRate: 0,
          quantity: 2,
          category: "",
          brand: "",
          dimension10: "xxx"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          name: "product2",
          price: "xxx",
          unitPriceLessTax: "xxx",
          unitPriceWithTax: "xxx",
          taxRate: 0,
          quantity: 1,
          category: "",
          brand: "",
          dimension10: "xxx",
          variant: "xxx"
        }
      ]
    }
  } }

  var result = a.ecommerce.purchase.products.map(({name, quantity}) => ({name, quantity}));

  //You can do an .each here or loop
  result[0].productName = result[0].name;
  delete result[0].name;

  result[1].productName = result[1].name;
  delete result[1].name;

  var output = { lineItems:
      result
  }

  alert("Result:" + JSON.stringify(output));
```

In edition of the question I've added the columns name changing.

Comment: Since I´m working with GTM datalyaer I´m getting this:  Error at line ..., character 56: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015...etc.

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused what  you're saying

Comment: Basically I´m running the map.function as GTM variable and then in the GTM tag I´m trying to get the expected json result by passing product quantity and product name.

Comment: Add GTM in the tags of your question, it will help the searches of future.

Comment: editor's note: do not add requests for clarifications in answers, that's what the comment section is for.