# How to change key names in an array (javascript and Google Tag Manager)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, google-tag-manager

I'm configuring ecommerce tracking for GA4 in Google Tag Manager. I don't have access to the source code, but I do have access to Google Tag Manager.

The website is populating ecommerce variables on the order confirmation page, but they are using old ecommerce schema (analytics.js) which is not compatible with GA4.

I want to add the new key names, set these values equal to the value of the old key names and then remove the old key names.

**Existing array:**

```
[(
'sku': 'abc123456', 
'name': 'productA', 
'category': 'BrandName', 
'quantity': 1, 
'price': 18.00
)]
```

**The array I want:**

```
[(
'item_id': 'abc123456', 
'item_name': 'productA', 
'item_category': 'BrandName', 
'quantity': 1, 
'price': 18.00
)]
```

I'm using a javascript variable {{transactionProducts}} to grab the products array. Then I've created a custom javascript variable to add the keys 'item_id', item_name', 'item_category'.

I tried using the delete operator to remove the old keys but this results in the new keys I created having a value undefined.

**Note**: google tag manager will not accept the map function. I believe it is limited to ES5?

```
function()
{
var products = {{transactionProducts}};
products.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.item_id = obj.sku;
  obj.item_name = obj.name;
  obj.item_category = obj.category;
  delete obj.sku;
  delete obj.name;
  delete obj.category;
});
return products;
}
```

**The Problem:**
When I run the above function in a custom JS variable in GTM, it does add the new key names, but their values become 'undefined'.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921657/get-the-proper-json-output-with-javascript-map-function-in-google-tag-manager) shows using `map()` in GTM. I don't think it's an ES6 method.

Comment: I can't see any reason why your code would cause the new keys to be undefined. If you had the `delete` statements first, that would do it.

Comment: Are you sure the original objects have those keys?

Comment: Your objects have `()` where it should be `{}`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/k0edntb3/2/

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your help and linking to that other question. It seems the issue was that the script was not running correctly while in Preview/Debug mode in GTM. Once I published the container, this worked correctly!